# firebase premession weird false

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I have a React App, connected to firebase db, that have multiple collections, "users" for hold users data and collection for each id.

I want that access to each collection will be available only for the user, but security rules are giving me unexpected `false` for the checker if `('/' +request.auth.uid) == collection`.

[image: fireBase console screenshot]

---

```
match /{collection = **}/{city} {
    allow read : if request.auth != null
    allow create, write, delete: if ('/' +request.auth.uid) == collection;
}
```

I don't want to cancel the check that the user is indeed the one responsive to `collection`, and only check if the `request.auth != null`, but don't sure why it is blocking me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It happens because `collection = **`, with just `collection`, all works as expected